# Circular Arrow in the middle of cd without tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, commutative-diagrams

I have the following commutative diagram

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \matrix (m)[matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em, column sep=4em, minimum width=2em , text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.5ex ] {E|_{\pi^{-1}(U_{\alpha})} & U_{\alpha} \times \mathbb R^k & W_{\alpha} \times \mathbb R^k \\ U_{\alpha} & U_{\alpha} & W_{\alpha}\\};

\path[-stealth]
(m-1-1) edge node [left]{$\pi$} (m-2-1)
    edge node [above] {$\varPhi_{\alpha}$} (m-1-2)
(m-2-1) edge node [above] {id} (m-2-2)       
(m-2-2) edge node [above] {$\varphi_{\alpha}$} (m-2-3) 
(m-1-2) edge node [above] {$\varphi_{\alpha} \times id $} (m-1-3)
(m-1-2) edge node [left] {$\pi_1$} (m-2-2)
(m-1-3) edge node [right] {$\pi_1$} (m-2-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I need to draw a circular arrow in the middle of both columns. Can I do that without using tikz-cd?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `tikz-cd`?

Comment: Couldn't install it. I'm still trying to make it work on my computer.

Comment: Do you have TeX Live or MiKTeX?

Comment: No. I have TeX Maker.

Comment: Tex maker is an editor, its only relationship with latex it that it calls latex to compile the code you write. If you are on Windows you're most likely using miktex or texlive and you can use either system to install `tikz-cd` (unless you are using a very old installation in which case: upgrade), all other systems use something derived from texlive.

Comment: I have to say that I am not so familiar with all terminologies. Probably Miktex then. Do you know any link or website where I could get more information from about this? On how to install tikz-cd.

Comment: Both systems have a package manager. You can know which is installed from the Control Panel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like this?  I same your commutative diagram in an `\hbox` and then inset huge circular arrows atop it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{amssymb,stackengine}
\newsavebox{\tmp}
\begin{document}
\setbox0=\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
     \matrix (m)[matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em, column sep=4em, minimum width=2em , text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.5ex ] {E|_{\pi^{-1}(U_{\alpha})} & U_{\alpha} \times \mathbb R^k & W_{\alpha} \times \mathbb R^k \\ U_{\alpha} & U_{\alpha} & W_{\alpha}\\};
%
\path[-stealth]
(m-1-1) edge node [left]{$\pi$} (m-2-1)
    edge node [above] {$\varphi_{\alpha}$} (m-1-2)
(m-2-1) edge node [above] {id} (m-2-2)       
(m-2-2) edge node [above] {$\varphi_{\alpha}$} (m-2-3) 
(m-1-2) edge node [above] {$\varphi_{\alpha} \times id $} (m-1-3)
(m-1-2) edge node [left] {$\pi_1$} (m-2-2)
(m-1-3) edge node [right] {$\pi_1$} (m-2-3);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\savebox{\tmp}{\box0}

\stackinset{c}{-1.5cm}{c}{}{\Huge$\circlearrowleft$}{%
\stackinset{c}{+1.5cm}{c}{}{\Huge$\circlearrowright$}{%
\usebox{\tmp}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If one needs bigger circle-arrows, a `\scalebox{}{}` can do the trick.